# Method to download website source returns nothing

Tags: java, android, web-scraping

I created method to download any url's source and show it in textview called checkView but when I call it with button it returns me empty textview instead of string with website code:

```
void getWebsite(String search) {

    String res = null;

    try {

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        URL url = new URL("http://drinkify.org" + search);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                conn.getInputStream()));

        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {

            sb.append(line + NL);
            res = sb.toString();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    checkView.setText(res);
}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, add a log-statement or a breakpoint to see if the text is actually downloaded.
My guess is that you get an exception (missing INTERNET-permission in the manifest?) that gets swallowed in your `catch (Exception e)`, add a breakpoint within the catch clause to test it.